# python time difference in second

Tags: python, linux

I have some process started on `X` time now i want to check duration so i wrote python script to diff time. here is the code which giving me second in `negative` number, can i get that value in positive without using extra `split` function

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.now() # after a few seconds
>>> delta = a-b
>>> delta.total_seconds()
-6.655989
```

Comment: I removed your update, this belongs to another question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are deducting the later date from the earlier, you need to reverse the logic:

```
b - a
```

You can use `abs` but if you know which date comes first it is unnecessary.

```
In [30]: from datetime import datetime    
In [31]: a=  datetime.now()    
In [32]: b = datetime.now() # after a few seconds    
In [33]: delta = b - a    
In [34]: delta.total_seconds()
Out[34]: 3.233579
```

Comment: No worries, datetimes can be confusing at the best of times.

Comment: I have updated my question with extra text do you know how do i diff time if i have in `13:47:06` format

Comment: I presume that is a string?

Comment: If you want to make a datetime object `datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")` but that is not going to work comparing against the current time.

Answer (score 1):

`abs` will do the trick

```
>>> abs(-2.3)
2.3
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) states:

> Return the absolute value of a number. The argument may be a plain or long integer or a floating point number. If the argument is a
>   complex number, its magnitude is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` **rises** as time continues, so that would mean you must subtract the past time from the current time.

```
difference = now - past
```